# MongoDB query $unset inside Cloud Function (Node JS 16) not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-cloud-functions

I have this query running on my Firebase cloud Function :

```
const result = userCollection.updateOne({ _id: "user1"}, {"$unset": testField});
```

And it throws the error :

```
Unhandled error ReferenceError: testField is not defined
    at /workspace/index.js:153:67
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:438:26
```

I can't find sample codes anywhere to make it work.
I have also tried to do :

```
const result = userCollection.updateOne({ _id: "user1"}, {"$unset": "testField"});
```

But got a MongoDB error :

```
MongoServerError: Modifiers operate on fields but we found type string instead. For example: {$mod: {<field>: ...}} not {$unset: "testField"}
```

What is the correct syntax here please ?

Note : I make a `$set` query that is actually working fine :

```
userCollection.updateOne({ _id: "user1"}, {"$set": {testField: "test"}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you are using for `$unset` is the [one in aggregation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unset/).

From [official doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/), the correct syntax to be used in update should be

```
{ $unset: { <field1>: "", ... } }
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/S_lwHejwET3)

Comment: i am guess i am too tired today, i just read the official doc before but didn't notice the `: ""` to make it work.. Thanks for your quick answer !